Files uploaded to Named Internal Stage using SnowCLI 2.7.0 not visible via Snowsight
Using a connection which uses Role SYSADMIN who owns the Named Internal Stage, I used SnowCLI to upload files using SnowCLI 2.7.0 on Windows 10, with success/no error, but the files were not visible to SYSADMIN in Snowsight
I used:
snow stage copy --overwrite project1.zip @schema.ST_SNOWPARK
and
snow snowpark package upload --file="project2.zip" --stage="@schema.ST_SNOWPARK"
The command snow stage list-files @schema.ST_SNOWPARK confirmed these files were present, in addition to correctly displaying other files manually uploaded and visible in the same stage in Snowsight
What could be the cause?

If you are viewing /data/databases//schemas//stage/, you will not see contents unless you enable directory table on the stage. You also need to refresh the directory table. If you are using Snowsight and issuing the ls or LIST command, you should be able to see staged files regardless of the directory table setting if you have permissions.
